# Dynamically including all available custom dimensions in BigQuery select statement

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

We are using a query similar to the one below for a report

```
SELECT 
visitId AS  visitId,
hits.hitNumber  AS  hits_hitNumber,
hits.time   AS  hits_time,

hits.page.pagePath  AS  hits_page_pagePath,

-- hit scope custom dimensions
(SELECT value from hits.customDimensions where index=1) AS CD1,
(SELECT value from hits.customDimensions where index=2) AS CD2,
-- user and session level custom dimensions
(SELECT value from sessions.customDimensions where index=3) AS CD3

FROM `ga_sessions_20191031` AS sessions, UNNEST(hits) as hits 
ORDER BY visitId, hits_hitNumber
LIMIT 50
```

The query uses un-nesting to flatten some of the custom dimensions. However the index values are hard coded in the query. So every time there is a new custom dimension defined, the query needs to be updated. Is it possible to use a subquery to select all available distinct index values and add them to the query dynamically ?

EDIT:

The following queries provide distinct index values : Is there a way to link them in first query ?

(hit scope )

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT cds.index as hit_cd_index
FROM `ga_sessions_20191031` AS sessions, UNNEST(hits) as hits,  UNNEST(hits.customDimensions) as cds 
ORDER BY hit_cd_index
```

(user and session scope )

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT session_cds.index as session_cd_index
FROM `ga_sessions_20191031`, UNNEST(customDimensions) as session_cds
ORDER BY session_cd_index asc
```

Comment: Just keep them in an array.

Comment: The goal is to finally generate a CSV export. So leaving in array format may not be useful.

Answer (score 0):

the most robust solution would be to add a table into your BigQuery dataset containing data from Management API so you'll be able to construct your select based on values from the most recent custom dimensions list: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/customDimensions/list

Comment: Rather than using a separate table , we are able to find distinct index values as shown in the EDIT above. The question still remains, if its possible to include them dynamically within the first query.